# Sorting an array alphabetically Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to collect a list and put them into an array then sort via the first letter of each item in the array. So far i have:

```
var cityArray = [];
  $("#addresses_list ul li .name").each(function() { cityArray.push($(this).text().trim()) });
  var finalArray = ['"' + cityArray.join('", "') + '"'];
  finalArray.sort();
  alert(finalArray);
```

This is collecting correctly and grouping into an array but still not sorting. Any idea why it's not? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Because `finalArray` has only one entry, the `cityArray` which you've turned into a string for some reason.

Comment: yeah i changed to have the sort on cityarray and that worked. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `cityArray` to sort before joining.

```
cityArray.sort();
```